# Getting a TypeError: wrong argument type Array (expected Module) with include java_import

Tags: java, include, jruby

I'm just starting using JRuby and when I test following code saved as a script

```
include java_import
frame = javax.swing.JFrame.new
frame.getContentPane.add javax.swing.JLabel.new('Hello, World!')
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation javax.swing.JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE
frame.pack
frame.set_visible true
```

I get the following error

```
Switch to inspect mode.
irb(main):001:0> include java_import
TypeError: wrong argument type Array (expected Module)
    from org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2068:in `include'
    from (irb):1:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1066:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1392:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174:in `catch'
    from C:\jruby-1.7.2\/bin/jirb_swing:54:in `(root)'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Can someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong? I have jruby-1.7.2 installed (C:\jruby-1.7.2), added to the PATH in system variables, and running on Windows 7. At the command prompt, I can test jruby and java version correctly

I also launched the jirb_swing via jruby(1.9.3).exe and at the prompt typed

```
irb(main):001:0> include java_import
```

and I get the same error message

**Update**

Hi All

After searching further on the Internet pages on JRuby and Java, I have resolved the problem successfully.

First the two ways that worked for me in calling Java from JRuby:

1. Using "include Java" (without the quotes in my script file and with capital J)
2. Using "require 'java'" (without the " quotes and notice the single quotes around java, now starting with lower-cap j)

The "java_import" I was using was an error on my part in being careless as I read the detailed document at GitHub (https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby)

I will research more about the differences or lack thereof in using the "include" vs. "require" statements and post back. As a real novice, this has been a real eye opener

Sri